# How would you properly install MATLAB in ubuntu that is running on WSL2?

Tags: linux, matlab, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

I want to install matlab in ubuntu 20.04, but I'm running ubuntu in WSL2 and it doesn't want to work.
I keep getting the error: `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'framework::window::DisplayError what(): No. Display Avaliable.`

I have the linux version of matlab unzipped in a folwer and I'm trying to instal it into the user files. Things I've tried to install it that were suggested for people having the same issue on other distros:

```
sudo ./install
./install
bash install
install
bash ./install
sudo bash ./install
sudo su and then doing ./install
export DISPLAY=:0.0 and then sudo ./install
bash ./install -v -inputFile installer_input.txt
```

It gives the same error for every one that I've tried.

Let me know if anyone has any solutions. Thanks.

Comment: YOu need an X server. See e.g. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-dev-appconsult/running-wsl-gui-apps-on-windows-10/ba-p/1493242

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this to help out others in the future. It actually involved a few things to get this fully working properly:

1)Had to get a X Server

2)Had to change display settings in ubuntu to get it to recognize the X server and turn off some firewall features for Windows.

3)Had to when installing matlab install  using the legacy install file instead of the normal install file

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion I gave was to use [WSLg](https://github.com/microsoft/wslg) to install the desktop version of MATLAB, which has the advantage of being a direct, interactive, graphical installation that doesn't "No. Display Avaliable" as you say.

I've tried [this approach in 2021](https://ww2.mathworks.cn/matlabcentral/answers/1597219-can-microsoft-s-wslg-windows-subsystem-for-linux-gui-support-running-matlab), but of course some people have successfully installed it normally, and the [official position is that MATLAB installation on WSL2 is not supported for the time being](https://ww2.mathworks.cn/matlabcentral/answers/1881447-can-i-use-matlab-or-other-mathworks-products-with-windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl-wsl2).